# How to redirect an entire site and all traffic but my ip address?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect

I have been looking on how to redirect all traffic to a certain page but my ip address but I can't find one I'm looking for... What I want to do is redirect the entire site not just one page to one certain page but not redirect my ip address. I have tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^123\.456\.789\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/page\.html$  
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/maintenance.html [R=302,L]
```

but it only redirects one page.. and I have too much pages to keep adding another `RewriteCond`

Answer (score 1):

this should work.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=123.456.789
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/maintenance.html [R=302,L]
```